# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.spi.json.JacksonJsonProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot

I just can not understand why the spring can not find the desired class
I tried many solutions, but they all did not give the desired result.Why can not find the desired class, although it is clearly registered in dependencies.With what it can be connected?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.elasticpath.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-unmarshaller</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: is the version correct <version>${jackson.version}</version>?.
did you try specifying is explicitly like : <version>2.9.8</version>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question and replace the image with the text that the image is showing. Images of text are not searchable, nor are they accessible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```